# CardView for android not importing

Tags: android, cardlayout

I got the jar file of Card View from

```
sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\cardview-v7\21.0.0-rc1
```

and I tried the example from this [link1](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html#cardview) and [link2](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui-widgets)

I was able to do for Recycler but for card view it is shwoing the error in xml for importing `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` in XML layout

and the detailed error is

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardCornerRadius' in package 'com.cards.cardlayoutui'
```

Comment: to elaborate more on this issue, you don't have that resource by just adding the classes.jar file. Your best bet is to either import my library below, and add the classes.jar file to that as a dependency or manually create what i have on github then add the dependency for the classes.jar

Answer (score 0):

Please see my post on GitHub: https://github.com/lt-tibs1984/CardViewLibrary This should walk you through how to take this project, and use the downloaded SDK for CardView. I will be updating this tonight as I Can.

Basically, the problem is that when you unpack the zip file and import only the jar file you have no resources associated to the card view.

Just download my zip file, import that as existing code into a workspace, then add the classes.jar as the libraries dependency!

Directions available in the read me

**Update**

The original project for this answer neither still relevant nor still exists.

To use Cardview in your project,

Add

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

or if using androidx:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

to your app's `build.gradle`

Comment: @HarshaVardhan there is no more project on my github for this answer as it is no longer relevant. Please see my update if you want to use Cardview

Comment: but i think design library automatically providing this

Answer (score 0):

try to add values xml file and follow this tutorial may be it will help

http://treyrobinson.net/blog/android-l-tutorials-part-3-recyclerview-and-cardview/

Comment: I am using eclipse. Do you have the link for library file of Recycler List / Card List.

Comment: which eclipse you are using??

Comment: I am using eclipse kepler